# Консольное приложение останавливается до ручного введения текста

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события

Что имеем:
Есть консоль, исполняющая роль сервера. В консоли запускается задание (каждый час делает действие). При каждом исполнении действия происходит вывод текста в консоль. Задание выполняется в отдельном потоке, поэтому устроено это так

```
private static void Task_SendMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Сообщение от фоновой задачи: " + message);
}
```

Соответственно, в message приходит сообщение. Параллельно пишутся логи.

А теперь проблема. В некоторых случаях выполнение задания останавливается на моменте послания сообщения до того момента, как я не подойду к компьютеру и не нажму любую кнопку на консоли.

Вызов события происходит так:

```
SendMessage?.Invoke("сообщение")
```

Если отключить посылку сообщения все срабатывает правильно. Пока не смог понять, от каких именно факторов зависит остановка или не остановка выполнения задания.

Может кто встречался с такой проблемой.

Comment: Пишут что такое происходит если в консоли выделен текст: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275480/console-writeline-gets-stuck А вообще, на сервере надо логи писать, а консоль скрыть

Comment: Надо будет протестировать, кстати. А сообщения уже да, убрал почти везде...

Comment: @Vasya Если уж вам очень нужно выводить в консоль, то сделайте очередь вывода, которую заполняйте сообщениями вывода на консоль, а в отдельном потоке проверяйте эту очередь например с определенной периодичностью и пытайтесь вывести текст на консоль.

Comment: Сообщения в консоль были введены, в основном, для дебага. При постоянном использовании они не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Только что протестировал. Первый комментатор оказался прав.

Стоит такое же событие на получение сообщение по сокету. Выделил текст, перевел фокус на другое приложение, послал сообщение консоли. Она не реагировала, пока я не ввел текст.
[default locale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178556/default-locale), спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашелся на английском Stack Overflow: [Console.WriteLine(“”); gets stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275480/console-writeline-gets-stuck). Резюмирую ответы оттуда.

При выделении текста окно консоли ожидает следующее действие от пользователя: изменение выделения, либо копирование текста с помощью Enter. До тех пор консоль блокирует вывод.

Что можно сделать:

- выводить сообщения не в консоль, а в лог;
- усилием воли не выделять текст, либо каждый раз снимать выделение;
- отключить для консоли выделение, при этом скопировать не получится, но и блокироваться ничего не будет (см. [How to programmatic disable C# Console Application's Quick Edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656846/how-to-programmatic-disable-c-sharp-console-applications-quick-edit-mode));
- выводить в консоль в асинхронном режиме (см. [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323736/451518)), при этом будет блокироваться только вывод, а алгоритм продолжит работу.